# how to display modified webpage without clearing cache

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My website is hosted by blue host.

Whenever I modify/add text in the HTML and I refresh my webpage, the change would be reflected.

However, when I update the css file, i must clear my chrome brower cache in order to reflect the change.

This is painful as I need to constantly clear my cache. Sometimes tweaking format takes several such clearing.

Is there any way i could avoid clearing the cache but still reflect the css related changes?

Comment: Ctrl+f5 to clear cache, or change the name of your css file every time you edit it

Comment: it is ctrl + shift + delete in windows.
and change name of css each time seems more work than clearing cache?

Comment: Ctrl+f5 will do it on Firefox and chrome on Windows. And yep renaming resources by hand way too much work, some frameworks can be configured to automatically add a random token to force unique names, but those are your options whether you like it or not 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

-reload the page with cntr+shft+R

-add a dummy Parameter to your css file which you change when you need to refresh the css. E.g. .../yourpath/css.css?v=1
(In case you can use scripts such as PHP, you can use a random value for this parameter which will automatically force the css-reloading on each page refresh)

-open the developer console (F12) and disable the cache on the network tab.

Comment: thanks. I am new to webpage, let me study what you have discussed here.

Comment: I tried disable cache in the network tab, it somehow doesn't work.

but i like the ctrl+shift+R option. Thanks.